# Design Pattern with Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am struggling on how to implement redux toolkit on my project. I have an API that fetches `Setup` objects. Each of these objects is quite big with a lot of properties. My initial approach was to use RTK to fetch all of the objects but only with the `name` and `id` props. Then, have a separate slice for a single full `Setup` object that will store all the props of the selected `Setup`. This is causing a lot of issues for me as state is not loaded appropriately. The current workflow looks as following. First, load all `Setups`. Then, through a dropdown select a single `Setup`. Then call an RTK query to fetch all the props of the `Setup`. Then, load all the props into the slice. And finally, display the props into a component.

Do you have any suggestions on how to implement this feature in a more simple and functional way? I have thought about loading all the props directly instead of just the id and name. Or have two RTKs. One with all the Setups and then another cached RTK for a single `Setup`. One thing to keep in mind is that I plan to then perform different operations on that single selected Setup such as changing the name, filters, etc.

This is a sample of the API I call to get all the `Setup` (only `name` and `id`):

```
[
    {
        "date": "Sat, 02 Jul 2022 00:14:50 GMT",
        "default": true,
        "id": "62bf8dfab60731051bcf77dd",
        "name": "Default 0"
    },
    {
        "date": "Thu, 30 Jun 2022 22:05:59 GMT",
        "default": false,
        "id": "62be1e47d4c5f49eb95cd06d",
        "name": "Filter Setup"
    }
]
```

This is a sample of all the props of a single `Setup`:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "62be1e47d4c5f49eb95cd06d"
    },
    "name": "Filter Setup",
    "default": false,
    "filters": [
        {
            "id": {
                "$oid": "62bf8d03b60731051bcf77db"
            },
            "name": "RRR greater than 1"
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "$oid": "62bf8d09b60731051bcf77dc"
            },
            "name": "RRR greater than 1"
        }
    ],
    "state": {
        "schema": {
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "index",
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                {
                    "name": "#",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                {
                    "name": ".m_RRR",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                {
                    "name": ".r_Result",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                {
                    "name": ".r_Result 50% Candle SL",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                {
                    "name": ".m_Entry Candle",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": ".m_Zone Touch #",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                {
                    "name": ".m_Zone Origin",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                {
                    "name": ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": ".m_Fast Into Profits",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": ".m_Trade @ Range Over",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": ".m_Checked",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": ".p",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "primaryKey": [
                "index"
            ],
            "pandas_version": "0.20.0"
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "#": 1.0,
                ".m_RRR": 3.37,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Hammer",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 2.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 1.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 1,
                "#": 2.0,
                ".m_RRR": 2.43,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Hammer",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 3.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 2,
                "#": 3.0,
                ".m_RRR": 2.29,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Engulfing",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 3.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 3,
                "#": 4.0,
                ".m_RRR": 2.97,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Engulfing",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 3.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 4,
                "#": 5.0,
                ".m_RRR": 3.48,
                ".r_Result": null,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": null,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 4.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 5,
                "#": 6.0,
                ".m_RRR": 3.22,
                ".r_Result": 3.22,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": 3.22,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 4.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "Yes",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 6,
                "#": 7.0,
                ".m_RRR": 1.98,
                ".r_Result": 0.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": 0.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 5.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 7,
                "#": 8.0,
                ".m_RRR": 4.8,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 2.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 8,
                "#": 9.0,
                ".m_RRR": 4.59,
                ".r_Result": 4.59,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": 4.59,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 3.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 2.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "Yes",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 9,
                "#": 10.0,
                ".m_RRR": 1.71,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 2.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 10,
                "#": 11.0,
                ".m_RRR": 2.77,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 2.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 11,
                "#": 12.0,
                ".m_RRR": 2.15,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Hammer",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 3.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 12,
                "#": 13.0,
                ".m_RRR": 1.71,
                ".r_Result": 1.71,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": 1.71,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 2.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "Yes",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 13,
                "#": 14.0,
                ".m_RRR": 6.0,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 4.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 1.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "Yes",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 14,
                "#": 15.0,
                ".m_RRR": 6.48,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 4.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 1.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "Yes",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 15,
                "#": 16.0,
                ".m_RRR": 5.07,
                ".r_Result": 4.67,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": 4.67,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Hammer",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 2.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 1.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 16,
                "#": 17.0,
                ".m_RRR": 1.86,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 2.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 17,
                "#": 18.0,
                ".m_RRR": 3.87,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Hammer",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 8.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 1.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 18,
                "#": 19.0,
                ".m_RRR": 1.97,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 3.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 19,
                "#": 20.0,
                ".m_RRR": 3.25,
                ".r_Result": 3.07,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": 3.07,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 3.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "Yes",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 20,
                "#": 21.0,
                ".m_RRR": 4.15,
                ".r_Result": 0.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": 0.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 3.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 2.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 21,
                "#": 22.0,
                ".m_RRR": 2.44,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 3.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 22,
                "#": 23.0,
                ".m_RRR": 3.9,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 4.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "Yes",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 23,
                "#": 24.0,
                ".m_RRR": 1.92,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 4.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 0.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            },
            {
                "index": 24,
                "#": 25.0,
                ".m_RRR": 2.66,
                ".r_Result": -1.0,
                ".r_Result 50% Candle SL": -1.0,
                ".m_Entry Candle": "Spinning",
                ".m_Zone Touch #": 4.0,
                ".m_Zone Origin": 1.0,
                ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level": "No",
                ".m_Fast Into Profits": "No",
                ".m_Trade @ Range Over": "No",
                ".m_Checked": "No",
                ".p": "AUDUSD"
            }
        ]
    },
    "notes": "",
    "author": {
        "$oid": "6175d1ad7d0ea08fbd85cc2c"
    },
    "documentId": {
        "$oid": "62bdb1e4acbe566f0779271d"
    },
    "date_created": {
        "$date": 1656626759825
    },
    "options": [
        {
            "id": ".m_RRR",
            "name": "RRR",
            "type": "number"
        },
        {
            "id": ".m_Entry Candle",
            "name": "Entry Candle",
            "type": "string",
            "values": [
                "Hammer",
                "Engulfing",
                "Spinning"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": ".m_Zone Touch #",
            "name": "Zone Touch #",
            "type": "number"
        },
        {
            "id": ".m_Zone Origin",
            "name": "Zone Origin",
            "type": "number"
        },
        {
            "id": ".m_Re-entry @ Other Level",
            "name": "Re-entry @ Other Level",
            "type": "string",
            "values": [
                "No"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": ".m_Fast Into Profits",
            "name": "Fast Into Profits",
            "type": "string",
            "values": [
                "No",
                "Yes"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": ".m_Trade @ Range Over",
            "name": "Trade @ Range Over",
            "type": "string",
            "values": [
                "No",
                "Yes"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": ".m_Checked",
            "name": "Checked",
            "type": "string",
            "values": [
                "No"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": ".p",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string",
            "values": [
                "AUDUSD"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Something like Apollo GraphGL might be useful for you. A GraphQL query could pull in the objects in the exact shape/schema you want, so it's more organized for you. Otherwise, you might want to make some kind of parsing utility function to clean up the response object into a new type of object.

Comment: Other than some cleaning with the `id.$oid` and `pandas_version` I will be using all of the props of the object. So I do not think that cleaning would help excesively. The question is more about how to use redux-toolkit to fit the needs of the feature.